# Justification that (a,b] in the standard topology is not closed?

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering how to justify that $(a,b]$ is not closed in the standard topology on **R**. I know that the definition of a closed set is one whose complement is open. So then we have that

**R** - (a,b] = $(-\infty,a] \cup (b,\infty)$.

So the set $(b,\infty)$ is an open ray which is open in the standard topology. And the set $(\infty,a]$ is closed because its complement is the open ray $(a,\infty)$.

So I have that **R** - (a,b] is the union of a closed set and an open set but does that necessarily mean then that $(a,b]$ is not closed? It doesn't seem like quite enough to me. Perhaps there is some way to write $(\infty,a]$ as an infinite union of basis elements in the order topology that I just haven't thought of?

P.S. I was hoping to get clarification from as pure of a topological standpoint as possible in terms of sets in the topology or basis for the topology, I know there are lots of other ways to answer this question if you look at sequences, seq. compactness and the metric on **R**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}$, a set $U$ is open if and only if for every $x\in U$ there is an interval $(c,d)$ such that $x\in (c,d)\subseteq U$. Take $x=b$. If $x\in (c,d)$ then we have $c<b<d$, and so $(c,d)\not\subseteq (a,b]$.

Comment: Oh I see now, I forgot to think about plain old basis elements for the topology and why it wouldn't work at that particular point. The only time that there exists basis elements of the form (c,d] are when X has a maximum element d... and $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't have one. Thanks very much! I need to keep that in mind, I've been working more with the complementing characterization lately so I kind forgot about the characterization involving basis elements.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a set $V \subseteq \Bbb R$ is open if and only if for all $v \in V$ there exists some $\varepsilon >0$ such that the interval $(v-\varepsilon, v+\varepsilon) \in V$.

If we consider the set $(-\infty,a]\cup(b,\infty)$, we find that for the point $a$ we run into trouble, since there does not exist a $\varepsilon$ such that the above definition of open sets holds. Therefore the set is not open and subsequently, $(a,b]$ is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

*(This had been a comment, but I thought it might be of sufficient interest to others to post as an answer, even though it doesn't really answer the spirit of the question.)*

For a [hammer proof](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=78358) (see [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=206856) also), the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) says that for a normal topological space, every continuous function from a closed set in the space to the reals has a continuous extension to the whole space, but $f: (0,1] \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous but has no continuous extension to all of ${\mathbb R},$ so $(0,1]$ can't be a closed set.